# Uniform convergence of derivatives onopen interval

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $f_n(x):(a,b)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, $n\in\mathbb{N}$, and
>
> (1) $f_n(x)$ differentiable on $(a,b)$;
>
> (2) $\exists~x_0\in(a,b)$ such that $\displaystyle\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}f_n(x_0)$ exists;
>
> (3) $f_n'(x)$ converges uniform to a function $g(x)$ for $x\in(a,b)$;
>
> Does $f_n(x)$ converges uniform to a function $f(x)$ for $x\in(a,b)$?

A well-known result with open interval changed by closed interval. I think the result above is not correct ,but I can't give a counterexample QAQ. Thanks for your answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is still true for a *bounded* open interval.

By the MVT, for any $x \in (a,b)$ there exists $\xi$ between $x$ and $x_0$ such that 
$$|f_m(x) - f_n(x)| = |f_m(x_0) - f_n(x_0) + [f_m'(\xi) - f'_n(\xi)](x - x_0)| \\ \leqslant |f_m(x_0) - f_n(x_0)| + |f'_m(\xi) - f'_n(\xi)|(b-a).$$

Using (2) and (3) we can find for any $\epsilon >0$ a positive integer $N$ depending only on $\epsilon$ and perhaps $x_0$, but independent of $x$, such that if $m >n > N$ we have

$$|f_m(x) - f_n(x)| < \epsilon.$$

Since the sequence $(f_n)$ is uniformly Cauchy, it is uniformly convergent on $(a,b)$.